# How can I store history of each tree node in memory without any leaks?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have "tree-like" dictionary. The problem is following: the memory is quickly consumed and not cleared (from 100mb at start to 3gb)
And the main problem in this tree is history of each node.

If I remove all code inside this block: `if(level >= topic.Length)`  (before `return false;`) everything will be okey and memory will clear

How can I store history of each node in memory without any leaks?

```
public class TreeNode
{
    protected TreeNode(string part) : this(part, -1, null) {}
    
    private TreeNode(string part, int level, TreeNode? parent)
    {
        Part = part;
        Level = level;
        Parent = parent;
        Root = parent?.Root ?? this;
        
        if(parent!=null)
          MessagesCount = 1;
    }
    private int _historyId;
    public int Level { get; }
    public TreeNode? Parent { get; }
    public TreeNode Root { get; }
    [Reactive] public string Part {get;set;}
    [Reactive] public string? Header {get;set;}
    [Reactive] public string? Payload {get;set;}
    [Reactive] public string? Topic {get;set;}
    [Reactive] public MqttDelivery? Delivery {get;set;}
    [Reactive] public int MessagesCount {get;set;}
    [Reactive] public int TopicsCount {get;set;}

    public ObservableCollection<ReceivedHistoryMessage> UiHistoryMessages { get; set; } = new();
    public readonly Dictionary<string, TreeNode> _treeChildren = new();

    public bool Add(
      string[] subTopic,
      MqttDelivery delivery)
      => Add(subTopic, Level + 1, delivery);

    private bool Add(
      string[] topic,
      int level,
      MqttDelivery delivery)
    {
        if(level >= topic.Length)
        {
            Topic = delivery.Topic;
            Header = delivery.Header?.ToJsonString(true);
            Payload = delivery.Payload?.ToJsonString(true);
            Delivery = delivery;
           
            AddToHistory(delivery);
            return false;
        }

        var part = topic[level];
        if(!_treeChildren.TryGetValue(part, out var trie))
        {
            TopicCount++;
            _treeChildren.Add(part, trie = new TreeNode(part, level, this));
        }

        MessagesCount++;
        trie.Add(topic, level+1, delivery);

        return true;
    }

    private void AddToHistory(MqttDelivery mqttMessage)
    {
       while(UiHistoryMessages.Count >= 30)
          UiHistoryMessages.RemoveAt(UiHistoryMessages.Count - 1);

       UiHistoryMessages.Insert(0, new ReceivedHistoryMessage()
       {
          Id = _historyId++,
          Time = DateTime.Now,
          Message = mqttMessage,
          UIFormattedMessage = $"{DateTime.Now:mm:ss}, {mqttMessage.Header.ToJsonString()}"
        
       });
    }
}
```

I add to collection following:

```
public class ReceivedHistoryMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? UIFormattedMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public MqttMessage? Message { get; set; }
}

[Name( "message" )]
public partial class MqttMessage
{
    public MqttMessageHeader Header { get; set; } =
        new();

    public JObject Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As you keep only 30 messages, you may use a table of 30 items as history storage , keep the index of the last inserted or overwritten one. To avoid releasing/allocating memory, use fixed length buffers to store strings.

Comment: Whenever you find to much memory being used, use a memory profiler to discover why. It should tell you what objects consume most memory. And more importantly, lets you check what objects have been added/removed between two snapshots. That should let you check if you are just using a lot of memory, or are actually leaking memory.

Comment: I used profiler and I saw a lot of json objects that stored in history of nodes. So the history of nodes is the main problem as I said. But I need this history and I just need to fix smth @JonasH

Comment: @Graffito like List<string> map = new(30); ?

Comment: UiHistoryMessages should be declared as an array of ReceivedHistoryMessage containing : Id (int), Time (DateTime), MessageBuffer (array of byte) and UIFormattedMessageBuffer (array of byte).

Comment: For string-buffer conversion, use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() and Encoding.UTF8.GetString().

Comment: I don't understand too much about MessageBuffer so I don't know will it work with my objects. I updated my question and you can check what object I add to collection

Comment: Buffers are arrays of bytes whose length is set to the maximum length, i.e. sufficient to contain any string you may store to history. Therefore, these arrays don't need to be reallocated. When you want to store a string, store the  byte encoding.  Define in  ReceivedHistoryMessage as many buffers as the number of strings in the structure(s) you want to add in the history.

Comment: How much does the JSON change from one payload to the next? Does it have a lot of information repeated between those?

Comment: Do a rough calculation , number of nodes x number of history messages x average size of each message. If that number is similar to your actual memory usage you need to cut *something* if you want to reduce memory usage. If it is much less, is the error in your calculation? your assumptions? your code?

Comment: no, information on each node doesn't change too much, maybe 1 row or 2. Sometimes it is much more but anyway @btilly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this question looks very much like, "How can I store data without using memory to store it in?"  So I'll answer that question.

First, why does it look like that question to me?  You have a 100 MB tree.  Each node is going to store up to 30 copies of itself. 30 x 100 MB = 3 GB.  That is how much memory you wind up using.  So you're using 3 GB of memory to store 3 GB of history.  You don't want to lose the history - you just want to use less memory.

The first trick to use is that instead of storing a stringified version of the JSON, store a **compressed** stringified version.  [Snappy](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java) is definitely worth a shot.  Fast, lightweight, and depending on what your data looks like you could save a lot of memory.

The second trick to consider is that you don't need to store each historical version.  Just store something from which you can reconstruct it.  So, for example, store the current version and then just store diffs from which old versions can be reconstructed.  This is how your source control system is able to keep a full history without an insane amount of memory usage.  To try this give [java-diff-utils](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-diff-utils/) a shot.  (You may need to play with this one a bit.)

The third trick is to modify your history requirement.  You're currently keeping 30 messages per node.  Can some of that history be moved to disk?  Do you wish to put it in an LRU cache so that you're keeping more memory on rapidly changing nodes than slowly changing ones, and this lets you reduce your overall storage requirements?  I'm not sure how much is under your control here, but this at least gives you a strategy to try.

Comment: I so appreciate you for your help, thanks a lot!